# word choice: served or worked as the principal of ABC School

Tags: word-choice

(1) Jack **worked** as the principal of ABC School for six years.

(2) Jack **served** as the principal of ABC School for six years.

Which verb is correct?

Comment: They're both correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both correct.  But the words have different meanings.  Some positions are considered to be "service", most notably we say that soldiers serve in the army.  Similarly when a role is much more important than the pay it receives you use "serve" ("he served as town mayor",  "she served on a jury").  By contrast you would never say "He served as a programmer at Microsoft".  There is no element of "service" in being a programmer.

So do you consider the role of Principal to one of service to the school and to the community? Or do you consider it a job like being a CEO of a company?
Your phasing tells the reader how you consider the role.